# android external SDCARD does not have write access?

Tags: android, permissions, sd-card

I am developing an application on three different devices 
1) Toshiba excite tablet, model no- AT300 
2) Android TV BOX
3) Android tv dongle and mini pc

Toshiba excite tablet and android tv box as SD card slots were we need to insert sd card into adapter and place it. These both devices as only read access.

Android tv dongle and Mini PC as Sd card slot were we do not use adapter, we can directly insert sdcard without any adapter. This device has both read and write access to sd card .

DO any one know why is it giving me only read access if I use my sd card with the adapter? 
And also DO I need to write any permissions in manifest file?  
Right now I am having two permissions

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Give me a solution were I can have write access to all my devices

Comment: did you notice that the two permissions is the same?

Comment: Yeah I did. DO we need any extra permissions other than those?

Comment: may I ask how you try to write to the sd card? So could you show some code? Usually you don't need any other permission.

Comment: ` File directory= new File(this.externalSDCardPath+"/test");
if(directory.exists())
       {
        
        File imagesDirectory= new File(this.externalSDCardPath+"/test/Images");
        
         if(!imagesDirectory.exists())
          {
          try
             {
             
           imagesDirectory.createNewFile();
             }
           
           catch(Exception e)
            {
             Log.d(TAG,e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
           
          }
        
        
       } `

Comment: If you mean using an SD to USB adapter, that has no standard Android support (as a storage location) so the details of any implementation that does make it to some degree accessable would be device specific.

Comment: try maybe String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test/Images";
  File path = new File(path);

Comment: That will create new folder in internal storage, I want in my external storage card